# Add 2 positive integers by playing with bits

Tags: code-golf, binary

Given 2 positive integers in any format you'd like, return their sum using only logic gates and bit shifts (see example below). Don't worry about overflow.

EDIT: Using pre-written addition is obviously not allowed. So no `a + b`, `Add(a, b)`, `a - (-b)` etc.

This is code golf, so [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply. Shortest program in characters wins.

Some test cases:

```
3, 4 => 7
5, 7 => 12
9, 10 => 19
12, 31 => 43
```

Example code in C#, readable (471 characters):

```
int Add(int numA, int numB)
{
    int result = 0;
    int mask = 1;
    int carryOver = 0;
    while (numA > 0 || numB > 0)
    {
        int A_bit = numA & 1;
        int B_bit = numB & 1;
        if ((carryOver ^ A_bit ^ B_bit) == 1)
        {
            result |= mask;
        }
        carryOver = carryOver == 1 ? A_bit | B_bit : A_bit & B_bit;
        numA >>= 1;
        numB >>= 1;
        mask <<= 1;
    }
    return carryOver == 1 ? result | mask : result;
}
```

Example code in C#, unreadable (118 characters):

```
int r=0,m=1,c=0;while(a>0|b>0){int A=a&1,B=b&1;if((c^A^B)==1)r|=m;c=c==1?A|B:A&B;a>>=1;b>>=1;m<<=1;}return c==1?r|m:r;
```

Comment: I see what you're trying to do with this challenge, but it's basically hopeless to get answers that "play with bits" by banning arithmetic operators. There's too many ways to "cheat" with built-ins like `sum` and string concatenation, and trying to ban these leads to ambiguity and disagreements about the spirit of the challenge. After many attempts at such challenges, the community has come to the conclusion that [Do X without Y](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8079/20260) challenges are a bad idea.

Comment: @xnor Using any other function to calculate it for you is obviously not allowed.

Comment: See [Patching out approaches](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8943/20260) and [Non-observable requirements](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20260) and other "Things to avoid".

Comment: If we must use bit-bashing, then it should be more firmly stated, and not rely on the spurious leap that not using arithmetic operators would implicitly force us to "play with the bits."

Comment: I've edited the question to explicitly state that you must use only logic gates and shifts.

Comment: @Bip Is [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/187500/43319) acceptable?

Comment: @Adám Yes, I don't know the language but according to your explanation you only played with bits.

Comment: @Bip Shouldn't you give others a chance before you accept an answer? Maybe someone who could beat my code length wasn't here during this past hour…

Comment: @Bip Since it looks like you want to only allow functions on a whitelist, take a look at the [tag:atomic-code-golf] tag. I think the best way to handle these is to describe a mini-language describing exactly what's allowed and how many points or characters each operation costs.

Comment: _using only logic gates and bit shifts_ But your example also uses logical branching (`if`, `?`), loops (`while`), arithmetical comparisons (`>`)... I'm afrait it is going to be hard to define the allowed operations throughly and without [making assumptions about language features](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8067/36398)

Comment: Hello welcome to the site.  This challenge could potentially be worked into something that meets our standards.  For that I would recommend putting it in the sandbox on the meta so that more experienced users can point out issues they see.

Comment: I've VTCed as unclear as your spec requires binary input but your test cases contradict that.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

Takes input as `(a)(b)`.

```javascript
a=>g=(b,r=0,m=1,c,y=a&m,z=b&m)=>m?g(b,!(y^z)^!c?r|m:r,m<<1,c?y|z:y&z):r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwFEXReVdhJ5IPaTVqEcWvOxFiqtJiTImlkODe0xQ7yuCNzuM@@YdvQj9e78uq7qOb0HFsZyQD1ZhSiYwKapDHklocYgnYym72eiamt9CfRad3WWsqm8ZfO7Pb2sQWau2EWje1jNdFzWQiUQq/QZQkUXoKLPdWHFaGdvNWHsayECsg7B9lVYAsA5KzA4vcfQE)

Comment: Looks like the spec (unnecessarily) requires input in binary.

Comment: @Shaggy Neither the test cases nor the example code seem to do that, though.

Comment: I think you overcomplicated it.

Comment: @DaniilTutubalin Definitely. It's just a port of the example code.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 28 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,b)=>b?f(a^b,(a&b)<<1):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hclBC0AwFADgu1/xTnqvNm07avgn6g0TyYT8/UluIpfv8o188Nasw7LLObRdjL5AFo6K0lUeuXYCOXVkraacYxPmLUxdNoUewSMAGHFBQMnztFICjFIvJ39Pf5@8L54)

Answer (score 2):

## [Logicode](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Logicode), 185 Bytes

Seeing as Logicode only has AND, OR, and NOT operators, I thought it might be fun to try to implement addition in Logicode for this challenge.

```
circ t(a,m)->cond a&m->1/0
circ x(a,b)->(a&!b)|(b&!a)
circ f(a,b,c,m,n)->cond n&10000000->0/f(a,b,(t(a,m)&(t(b,m)|c))|(t(b,m)&c),m+0,n+0)+x(x(t(a,m),t(b,m)),c)
circ a(a,b)->f(a,b,0,1,1)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsMgDIbvfYr2IoZGmrxA30XTbRSmwtigh767i9NBvSR/vs/oMz92ydutFNlfMr6txwhulZy20ZvoVl5o@KFDUVBkvZkCnDaYyUND94pQMGL6302GqR230tIE27YbrUHrKaBrWm8EMM6EaSaYD3t0FRsFlP6S759oCwkZGUr@qG1ZeyKAoUfSzHzJdUB8MXRUlSqVLw)

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc)

Not golfed to the max

```
c;d(a,b){while(b){
c=1;while(~b&c)b^=c,c<<=1;b^=c;
c=1;while( a&c)a^=c,c<<=1;a^=c;}
return a;}
```

Explanation, it's basically

```
while(b--)a++;
```

Will not work for negative b

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/ZOkUjUSdJs7o8IzMnVQPI4Eq2NbSG8OqS1JI1k@Jsk3WSbWyAoiCmNZK8QiJQPhEhD2Ja13IVpZaUFuUpJFrX/s9NzMzTAJpZUJSZV5KmoaSaEpOnpJOiYaxjoqlpjSFsqmOOTdhSx9AAm7ihkY6xIUii9j8A)

Comment: [85 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/ZOkUjUSdJszotv0jDOsk6Mc42GcJJtjW0rktSS7ZOtrGxNdRMAkpYgwmYZCJcDqTJurYotaS0KE8h0br2f25iZp6GZjVXQVFmXkmahpJqSkyekk6KhrGOiaamNYawqY45NmFLHUMDbOKGRjrGhiCJ2v8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 13 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Takes list of two equal-length binary representations.

```apl
⊃(≠/,1⌽¨∧/)⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8fku@UmfeobYKGoZm@keajjhmPupYcWsHlVpSfC5EwAost/f@oq1njUecCfR3DRz17D6141LFcX/NR7@JHnQv/pwGVPerte9Q31dMfqOzQeuNHbROBvOAgZyAZ4uEZ/B9qnkKaAthCBWMdBRMudEFTHQVzDEFLHQVDAwxRQyMdBWNDAA)

`(`…`)⍣≡` apply the following function until two consecutive applications are identical:

`∧/` AND of the two (lit. AND-reduce, so this enclose the result to reduce rank)

`1⌽¨` shift the content of that enclosure a single step left

`≠/,` prepend the XOR of the two (lit. XOR-reduction, so this also encloses)

eventually the all carries have been done, so the second element (AND) is all-zero

`⊃` pick the first element

Comment: Hey, I've downvoted this answer since I don't think one ought to leave answers if they are unclear on the challenge requirements.  I usually give people the benefit of the doubt when I am unclear on a challenge, but your comment asking if your answer is valid seems to indicate that you to are not entirely clear on what is allowed.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic I had no doubt at the time of posting, since OP said ***without using** the `+, -, /, *` operators of your language*. However, after I posted, OP was edited to say *only logic gates and bit shifts*, leaving me in doubt, since I also use fix-point, concatenation, and selection.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 65 bytes

```
+`(.?)(,\d*)(\d)
$2;$1$3
+`(.),
,;$1
{`00
0
01|10
1
}`;11
1;0
\D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxDgIxEAN7v2ORksvqtL6ATigFDc9IEaRQ0FAgOuDtYSNXtsd@3d@P523UniALUgtMsRKSDIfQjODwcL3EoLUvMdQeIVsRSp70GhXqDp9mBhe/NBC/VujbYqhXDHruNGc/H7MecdIdZ53wppl/) Link includes test cases in decimal; the header and footer perform base 2 conversion. Explanation:

```
+`(.?)(,\d*)(\d)
$2;$1$3
+`(.),
,;$1
```

Interleave the bits of both numbers, starting from the right.

```
{`00
0
01|10
1
}`;11
1;0
```

XOR each pair of bits together, and also AND the bits and carry 1 in that case. Repeat so that the carries propagate if necessary.

```
\D
```

Delete the separator punctuation.